# Apply Conditional Formatting based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm attempting to highlight a cell based on two conditions, if the Work Type is equal to `(blank)`, and if the cell itself is greater than 15%, then I want the cell under % Total Work highlighted. My sheet looks like this:

[image]

The only way I can think to do this is using the AND function, something like `=AND($B:$B="(blank)";$D:$D>.15)`, but this produces an error. I'm very new to conditional formatting, so I may be missing something obvious. I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to apply the formula that applies to the first cell in the range, so if you select the range `D8:D100` or similar (where data starts at row 8) then apply this formula in conditional formatting

`=AND(B8="(blank)";D8>0.15)`

That should do what you need

Comment: Thanks for your help @barry and @Harrison, I have a follow up question. It turns out the % Total Work column isn't actually in percentage format, but rather a string generated by some more advanced back-end scripts. Is there a way to compare that integer value to 15? I tried `=AND(B8="(blank)";MID(D8,1,5)>15)`, to try to extract just the number, but to no avail. I chose a length of 5 for the substring because the percentage value is actually longer than it appears, its just rounding. Thanks.

Comment: Try getting everything before % sign like this `=AND(B8="(blank)",LEFT(D8,FIND("%",D8)-1)+0>15)`